# 2 columns of a list, 1 scrollbar - is there a better solution?

Tags: lists, scrolling

This section is part of a larger form. Image shows a list. The reason I have 2 columns, is simply because I think it would be a waste of space, to just show 1 column. Most people have wide screens. I have this scrollbar, and the idea is that the scrollbar would move both sections with listed items, at once. But I am wondering, is there a better way to handle this?

Some technical information:

1. Documents cannot be divided in any other way, then perhaps by file format, and we have 3 now. But I don't think this is a good solution, because we are soon adding another 3 formats, so that's a total of 6...and may be more in the future.
2. The reason file names are so long, is because I am showing 64 characters, which is our character limit, for document names. I think there is value in showing the full name: no tooltips or other interaction, just to see full document name.
3. No limits on amounts of documents. There could be hundreds. Hence, the search bar, and document number label.
4. FYI, once these documents are uploaded, there is another, table view of them, with uploading status, but that's on another page.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is this design only supposed to be used on desktop? Seems like it could present some issue on mobile devices.

Comment: @MichaelLai Thank you for your question, Michael. Only desktop.